# Power function of a hypothesis test

Tags: statistics, statistical-inference

Let $X$ ~ Exp($\lambda$)

Consider testing $H_0 : \lambda \geq \lambda_0$ vs. $H_1 : \lambda < \lambda_0$

I'm trying to find the power function of the test that rejects the null hypothesis iff $X$ >= some constant c.

$\pi(\lambda | \delta_c$) = $1 - (1-\exp(-\lambda c))$ = $\exp(-\lambda c)$

Is that correct?

Additionally, I'm looking for a specific $c$ that gives our test size $\alpha$ on the interval  $0 < \alpha<1$ .

Answer (score 0):

This looks good.  The decay rate $\lambda$ is the true, unknown parameter.  Your alternative hypothesis is that the true value of $\lambda$ is smaller than some postulated value $\lambda_{0}$, which means that $X$ will decay more slowly .  So, your rejection region should have the form $[c,\infty]$ - you reject $H_0$ when $X$ is *large* (compared to the expected value under the null).

So, it's fine, as far as it goes.  But normally, you'd expect $c$ to depend on $\lambda_{0}$.  If you want to perform that test at the $\alpha$-level, then the critical region will be the upper $\alpha$-tail of $X$ under the null hypothesis.  Thus 
$\alpha=\textrm{e}^{-\lambda_{0}c}$.  Solving this for $c$ gives:
$$c=\frac{-\ln(\alpha)}{\lambda_0}.$$

The power is therefore 
$$\pi(\lambda)=\textrm{e}^{-\lambda \frac{-\ln(\alpha)}{\lambda_{0}}}=\alpha^{\frac{\lambda}{\lambda_{0}}}.$$